# How to access properties defined in "setup" function outside of the component?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

For example, we have a component `Woof` written with Vue 2 and `@vue/composition-api`.

```
<template>
  <div ref="borkElement" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api';

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Woof',

    setup() {
      const borkElement = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

      return {
        borkElement
      };
    }
  });
</script>
```

So I'd like to get access to element `borkElement` outside of the `Woof` component. It's available in the runtime, but TypeScript throws an error.

```
<template>
  <Woof ref="woofComponent" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api';
  import Woof from './Woof.vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
      const woofComponent = ref<typeof Woof | null>(null);

      return {
        woofComponent
      };
    },

    mounted() {
      console.log(this.woofComponent?.borkElement);
      //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^ property doesn't exist
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Terry It is. This is Vue 2 + composition API plugin. It's required to mention as it may affect answers.